# Update complex filter on ng-repeat from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers, and a shared service. Controller A is the main view for the page, containing an `ng-repeat` filled with data. Controller B contains the filtering options for the `ng-repeat` in Controller A. This works fairly well, and I've got a basic stripped down example of how I've got this working below.

My question is: How can I introduce much more complicated filtering in controller A? I know I'll need to use a function to do complicated filtering, and therein is the problem.

```
angular.module('app').factory('optionService', [/*'stuff'*/, options]);
function options(/*stuff*/){
    var someOption = false;
    var filters = {};
    var service = {
        someOption: someOption,
        filters: filters
    }
    return service;
}

angular.module('app').controller('controllera', ['dataSvc', 'optionService', ctrla]);
function ctrla(dataSvc, optionService){
    var vm = this;
    vm.options = optionService;
    vm.items = dataSvc.getItems();
}

angular.module('app').controller('controllerb', ['optionService', ctrlb]);
function ctrlb(optionService){
    var vm = this;
    vm.options = optionService;

    vm.toggleSomeOption = function(){
        vm.options.someOption = !vm.options.someOption;

        if(vm.options.someOption){
            vm.options.filters.someProperty = 'foo';
        } else {
            delete vm.options.filters['someProperty'];
        }    
    }
}

<div ng-controller="controllera as vm">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter:vm.options.filters">{{item.bar}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried putting a filtering method into the service, and adding it as the filter in the `ng-repeat`, but it doesn't fire when the options are updated.

Should I be using events or the `$rootScope` somehow to instead notify controllera that an option in controllerb has changed and it needs to update (e.g. by manually injecting a custom filter and running that)?

All in all I'm a bit confused as to how to get this working, and the best approach to take.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think the update is not happening because when the scope of ControllerB changes but angular does not know that it should check the scope of ControllerA as well.

You can start messing with `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$digest()` but they are very ugly and far from being "best practice". I'd rather recommend using a `$timeout(func, 0)` because that also leads to dirty check of the scope. So the process:

- ControllerA registers as some sort of a listener in the optionService
- ControllerB updates the options. This triggers the event
- ControllerA receives a trigger and calls a `$timeout()`. This way its scope will be aware of changes
- The `$timeout()` executes immediately and updates the scope of ControllerA
- The changes should be visible in the ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've managed to resolve this in what I think is an acceptable manner.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to implement this using `$rootScope.$broadcast` and `$scope.$on`.

In controller B, when the option is selected (it's a `checkbox`), I toggle the option stored in the service, and broadcast an event to say that the options have been updated. In controller A, the event is listened for, and the filter which is passed in as a dependency is applied and run against the complex filter method, which is just a bunch of if/elses (although that will get refactored out to somewhere else shortly).

```
angular.module('app').factory('optionService', [/*'stuff'*/, options]);
function options(/*stuff*/){
    var someOption = false;

    var service = {
        someOption: someOption
    }
    return service;
}

angular.module('app').controller('controllera', ['dataSvc', '$scope', 'filterFilter', 'optionService', ctrla]);
function ctrla(dataSvc, optionService){
    var vm = this;
    vm.options = optionService;
    vm.items = dataSvc.getItems();
    vm.filtereditems = [];

    function complexFilter(item){
        if(item.foo === 'bar' && vm.options.someOption){
            return true;
        }

        /* etc etc */
    }

    function runFilter(){
        vm.filtereditems = filterFilter(vm.items, complexFilter);  
    }

    $scope.$on('updated', function(){
        runFilter();
    };
}

angular.module('app').controller('controllerb', ['optionService', '$rootScope', ctrlb]);
function ctrlb(optionService, $rootScope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.options = optionService;

    vm.toggleSomeOption = function(){
        vm.options.someOption = !vm.options.someOption;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('updated');    
    }
}

<div ng-controller="controllera as vm">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in vm.filtereditems">{{item.bar}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's quite nice for a smaller project, however, polluting the `$rootScope` gets dangerous as the volume of the project grows.

Comment: Can you tell me or give an example why it is dangerous?

Comment: 1. The project can get very messy if everyone wants to communicate through `$rootScope`. 2. There is no good way to detect what messages are used (except making a global text search on the project). 3. In a very big application `$rootScope.$broadcast()` messages will reach *all* scopes in the whole page which is not efficient and also has the danger of name collisions. Keeping the inter-controller communication within services seems somewhat prettier solution -- but  it's more complex. Doesn't matter in a small project though.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I'll bear all that in mind.